Элементы, добавленные appendNode, появляются только после клика на родительский элемент. JavaScript
Есть HTML:
<svg id="svgElement"></svg>

Есть такой код:
const svgElement = document.getElementById("svgElement")

const rect = document.createElement("rect")
// настройка rect (Добавление атрибутов)

svgElement.appendChild(rect)

Элементы добавляются(в консоли есть), но показываться они начинают только после клика на svgElement
Заранее спасибо!

Что такое parent? Добавьте в вопрос определние parent и html разметку

Вместо createElement воспользуйтесь createElementNS

Спасибо, помогло
